# Update listView bound to dataSet dataTable which looks up data from SQL c# wpf

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, listview, datatable

I have a bit of an odd problem when trying to update a listView which is bouund to a dataSet.

The dataSet gets its information from SQL and needs to auto update every 5 mins. At the moment I am using a backgroudWorker to get the new info and insert it into the dataSet.

Then on the RunWorkerCompleted Event I do this

```
listView1.DataContex = dataSet.Tables["table"].DefaultView
```

The DoWork Event contains something like this

```
dataSet.Clear();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                "SELECT [ContainerID] ,[UserID], [Spur], [Wave] ,[Date] FROM [ScannedItems] " + 
                "WHERE [Message] LIKE '%Success%'" + 
                "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT [ContainerID] ,[UserID], [Spur], [Wave] ,[Date] FROM [Workstation].[dbo].[AllSpurs] " +
                "WHERE [Message] LIKE '%" + "Success" + "' ORDER BY [Date] DESC", connection);


            DataTableMapping mapping = adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Packages Scanned");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ContainerID", "Cont");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("UserID", "User");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Spur", "Spur");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Wave", "Wave");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Date", "Date");

            connection.Open();

            adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            connection.Close();
```

This works when I call worker.RunWorkerAsync(); at startup.

However when the timer calls it the tables go blank (all data removed). And if I try and scroll in the listVIew I get an error

```
Object reference not set to the instance of an object
```

However if I click the header of one of the columns the new data becomes visible and scrolling works.

Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong.

This is the XAML for the listView

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource cnListView}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}" Margin="7,5,31,7" Name="listView2" SelectionMode="Multiple" util:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True" LostFocus="LostFocus">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView x:Name="gridView1" AllowsColumnReorder="False" ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource cnDataViewHeader}">
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Cont}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Cont" Header="ContainerID" Width="350" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=User}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="User" Header="User" Width="200" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Spur}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Spur" Header="Spur" Width="120" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Wave, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Wave" Header="Wave" Width="250" />
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}" util:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Date" Header="Time Scanned" Width="250" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Thank You so much

Smaller Project complete code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="backWorkerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="502" Width="989">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MeetCollection}" Height="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="914">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Test2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test2}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="63" Name="button1" Width="288" Click="button1_Click" Margin="368,388,311,12" />
</Grid>
```

c#

```
namespace backWorkerTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    BackgroundWorker backWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataSet.Tables.Add("Stores");

        backWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backWorker_DoWork);
        backWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void GetData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CN-LT08\Nick;Initial Catalog=SorterAdmin;" +
                                                     "User=sa; Password=Altrincham09"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Store Number], [Store Name] FROM [Store_Info]", con);

            DataTableMapping mapping = sql.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Stores");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Store Number", "Test");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Store Name", "Test2");

            con.Open();
            sql.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
            sql.Fill(dataSet);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        dataSet.Clear();
        GetData();
    }

    private void backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["Stores"].DefaultView;
        listView1.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Seems like it should work but Table is repeated.  Try ItemsSource=Binding with no path.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited my XAML to have ItemsSource="{Binding}".  It still does not work. I can only assume that it is to do with the sorting code I am using. As when I click a column header it displays the correct info sorted and I can scroll. I cant tell why this would be a problem though?

Comment: I don't understand. Your XAML defines a ListView with Name='listView2' but then in your code you are setting listView1.DataContext = xxxx.... might be a typo?

Comment: One guess is the sort issues a refresh.  Try a refresh method.  After you rebind.

Comment: Thanks guys @HighCore yes that was a typo sorry. I have create a project which has this problem but without anyother code. Please see my edited post for the complete xaml and c# where this problem is still occurring.

Comment: @Blam that sounds like a good idea. I have tried listView1.UpdateLaytout() to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a refresh method. After you rebind.

Answer (score 0):

Update.

If the query is rather long, then the error occurs while the data is being read from SQL.

To stop this occuring I bing the listView to another table with identical data to the old version of SQL. The button click event is now

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable oldTable = dataSet.Tables["Stores"].Copy();
    listView1.DataContext = oldTable.DefaultView;
    listView1.Items.Refresh();

    backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Blam You were right. I added listView1.Items.Refresh(); to the RunComplete Event and now it works.

Thanks so much for your help everyone. In case anyone has the same problem below is the complete code for the small example with working backgroud updates.

C#

```
namespace backWorkerTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    BackgroundWorker backWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataSet.Tables.Add("Stores");

        backWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backWorker_DoWork);
        backWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    #region Fill dataSet
    void GetData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CN-LT08\Nick;Initial Catalog=SorterAdmin;" +
                                                     "User=sa; Password=Altrincham09"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Store Number], [Store Name] FROM [Store_Info]", con);

            DataTableMapping mapping = sql.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Stores");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Store Number", "Test");
            mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Store Name", "Test2");

            con.Open();
            sql.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
            sql.Fill(dataSet);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        backWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        dataSet.Clear();
        GetData();
    }

    private void backWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["Stores"].DefaultView;
        listView1.Items.Refresh();

        //MessageBox.Show("Complete");
    }
}
```

}

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="backWorkerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="502" Width="989">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MeetCollection}" Height="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="914">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Test2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Test2}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="63" Name="button1" Width="288" Click="button1_Click" Margin="368,388,311,12" />
</Grid>
```